# Traversing text in Insert mode

Tags: vim, vi

While in **Insert Mode** in Vim, is there any way to traverse the text moving some characters forward and backward other than using the arrow keys?

If I press <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd> and <kbd>l</kbd> while in Insert mode, the actual characters are printed on screen instead of moving through the text.

The way I'm doing it at the moment is having to resort to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> (<kbd>Esc</kbd>) and traversing the text then; but obviously that is not productive.

Comment: As an aside tip: it's also helpful if you map escape to a closer key combination (i.e. `imap jk <Esc>`) so that you don't have to break your momentum and reach across your keyboard to press the key.

Comment: I like it (`<ESC>`) mapped to `kj` instead of `jk`; my fellow friend _Dijkstra_ is to blame!

Comment: I have `jk` and `kj`, so I just press it like a big button with two fingers and doesn't matter the order I'm back on normal.

Answer (score 766, accepted):

While it may make sense that you should be able to use the <kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd> keys to traverse the editor in insert mode, but that is actually not the way Vim is intended to be used! There are many commands that Vim provides to make editing faster *and* easier.

The right way *is* to press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, go where you want to do a small correction, fix it, go back and keep editing. It is effective because Vim has much more movements than usual character forward/backward/up/down. After you learn more of them, this will happen to be more productive.

Here are a couple of use-cases:

- You accidentally typed "accifentally". No problem, the sequence <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>F</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> will correct the mistake and bring you back to where you were editing. The <kbd>F</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> movement will move your cursor backwards to the first encountered "f" character. Compare that with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>End</kbd>, which does virtually the same in a casual editor, but takes more keystrokes and makes you move your hand out of the alphanumeric area of the keyboard.
- You accidentally typed "you accidentally typed", but want to correct it to "you intentionally typed". Then <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> will erase the word you want to fix and bring you to insert mode, so you can immediately retype it. To get back to editing, just press <kbd>A</kbd> instead of <kbd>End</kbd>, so you don't have to move your hand to reach the <kbd>End</kbd> key.
- You accidentally typed "mouse" instead of "mice".  No problem - the good old <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> will delete the previous word without leaving insert mode. And it happens to be much faster to erase a small word than to fix errors within it.  I'm so used to it that I had closed the browser page when I was typing this message...!
- Repetition count is largely underused. Before making a movement, you can type a number; and the movement will be repeated this number of times. For example, <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> will bring your cursor 15 characters back and <kbd>4</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> will move your cursor 4 lines down. Start using them and you'll get used to it soon. If you made a mistake ten characters back from your cursor, you'll find out that pressing the <kbd>←</kbd> key 10 times is much slower than the iterative approach to moving the cursor. So you can instead quickly type the keys <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> (as a rough of guess how many characters back that you need to move your cursor), and immediately move forward twice with <kbd>l</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> to quickly correct the error.

But, if you *still* want to do small text traversals without leaving insert mode, follow [rson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155299/rson)'s [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737163/vim-traversing-text-in-insert-mode#comment1620134_1737259) and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>. Taking the first example that I mentioned above, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd><kbd>F</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> will move you to a previous "f" character and leave you in insert mode.

Comment: +1 Excellent answer and thanks for all the examples you gave!

Comment: It's also worth noting that you can use `Ctrl+o` to issue a single command in normal mode. This can at times get you where you want to be, especially when combined with the t/T and f/F movement commands.

Comment: This is the best answer to this topic, VIM is supposed to be used in normal mode most of the time, insert mode is just for - well - inserting text. If you don't fully use VIM's exceptional motion commands, you may as well use a non-modal editor.

Comment: "You seem to misuse vim, but that's likely that you're not very familiar with it." is a bit condescending. No?

Comment: @David, no, I don't think so, and neither Andreas does (see his comment above).  I wanted it to sound encouraging.

Comment: This is a great insight into how to use Vim properly. However, I find pressing "Esc" to be a pain, and so I think it's worth pointing out that you can map a more accessible key to that function, e.g. "imap jj <esc>".

Comment: good answer. but for the most common typos (the current/last word) it's often faster to backwards kill the word (db in normal mode) so I like to remap inoremap <C-h> <C-w> for that purpose.

Comment: To fix a typo you should **not** leave insert mode. Vim is powerful because you create atomic, repeatable actions. Inserting a typo, and fixing it creates two separate actions. The right way to fix a typo it to do it without leaving insert mode. If that mean using arrow keys to navigate there that is fine. Vim does have some keybindings to navigate in insert mode. Check `:h ins-special-keys`. `ctrl-h`: backspace, `ctrl-w`: delete word, `ctrl-u`: delete to beginning of line, `alt-b`: go back a word.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer; I'm really glad you chose to step back and focus on the philosophy of the action instead of just answering the question directly. This is not done enough on Stack Overflow. Also, for what it's worth, accidentally hitting "Ctrl+w" in a browser is a *huge* problem for me. Happens all too frequently...

Comment: How would I easiest rewrite `if(element.data('designer'))` to `if ( element.data( 'designer' ) )` ?

Comment: You can disable backspace in insert mode `inoremap <backspace>` which is a good way to force yourself to learn normal mode and vim movements

Comment: What exactly does the double pipe do? I can't seem to find any real good docs on it, that or I don't know what I am looking for

Comment: I disagree that you always have to get to normal mode to do navigation. VIM is meant for efficiency. Take for example when plugins which automatically insert right parenthesis when I type left parenthesis. So I have a situation where I **"print(a|)"**  - the pipe is where my cursor is. If have to move beyond the right parenthesis, I should [esc-l-i], three keys in sequence. This is not efficient.

Comment: Also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\[</kbd> might be faster to reach from the home row than <kbd>Esc</kbd> if one has a typical keyboard. ["The Vi editor was originally written on an ADM-3A terminal, which had the Escape key positioned where the Tab key occurs on most modern keyboards."](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoid_the_escape_key)

Comment: Esc bothers me on most US keyboards: have to leave home-row. Usually Ctrl-[ (control and left-bracket) is equivalent to Esc, and that I can manage easily form home-row. I don't see this mentioned often, but it made a big difference in deciding to stick with VIM.

Comment: Editor productivity is not the same as mathematically optimizing for the least amount of keystrokes in order to make a change. 1. Correcting a typo and pressing 8 distinct keys -- some of which modifier keys -- is not efficient in the heat of the moment. 2. Esc has a delay by default, Ctrl+C does not https://www.johnhawthorn.com/2012/09/vi-escape-delays/ . 3. Esc is far away.

I use Vim several hours per day but I don't pretend it's perfect. Tiny changes is a perfect example of where it's non-optimal. Blaming the user for not being a finger ninja is apologetic for no good reason.

Comment: What about the dot? Unfortunately, Ctrl+O breaks dot's beahviour :( I guess I'll stick with macros

Comment: i think it worth noting repetition count can be done with Ctrl+O
and interesting @KennyEvitt maybe i should consider mapping Esc to the tab key

Comment: `A` for the win.

Comment: It looks like it'd make more sense to just use VSCode and/or use Vim/Neovim but use the arrows (not hjkl) while in insert mode. "hjkl" are not even human-friendly.

Answer (score 228):

While in *insert mode*, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> to go to *normal mode* for just one command:

```
CTRL-O h  move cursor left 
CTRL-O l  move cursor right
CTRL-O j  move cursor down
CTRL-O k  move cursor up
```

which is probably the simplest way to do what you want and is easy to remember.

Other very useful control keys in insert mode:

```
CTRL-W    delete word to the left of cursor
CTRL-O D  delete everything to the right of cursor
CTRL-U    delete everything to the left of cursor
CTRL-H    backspace/delete
CTRL-J    insert newline (easier than reaching for the return key)
CTRL-T    indent current line
CTRL-D    un-indent current line
```

these will eliminate many wasteful switches back to normal mode.

Comment: Thank you. This should be considered the correct answer. It is actually helpful.

Comment: On my mac, it's lower-case o not upper case O. Is that different from "standard vim"? I see a lot of places where they appear to say upper case (unless that's just sloppy writing). Can you confirm?

Comment: Ok very useful. However, an interesting combination I have a hard time to find and this is remove line. Very underrated thing to do in case of accientially inserting a line.

Comment: @Floris Vim does not distinguish between upper and lower case letters for ctrl combinations. That's why it's not possible to map ctrl+shift+something.

Comment: `CTRL-H` is cash money. Can't believe how much keyboard traversal I've wasted reaching for the backspace key.

Answer (score 101):

## Insert mode

### Movement

#### hjkl

Notwithstanding what Pavel Shved [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737163/vim-traversing-text-in-insert-mode/1737259#1737259) - that it is probably more advisable to get used to <kbd>Esc</kbd>aping Insert mode - here is an example set of mappings for quick navigation within Insert mode:

```
" provide hjkl movements in Insert mode via the <Alt> modifier key
inoremap <A-h> <C-o>h
inoremap <A-j> <C-o>j
inoremap <A-k> <C-o>k
inoremap <A-l> <C-o>l
```

This will make <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> in Insert mode go one character left, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> down and so on, analogously to <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> in Normal mode.

You have to copy that code into your vimrc file to have it loaded every time you start vim (you can open that by typing `:new $myvimrc` starting in Normal mode).

#### Any Normal mode movements

Since the <kbd>Alt</kbd> modifier key is not mapped (to something important) by default, you can in the same fashion pull other (or all) functionality from Normal mode to Insert mode.  E.g.:
Moving to the beginning of the current word with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>:

```
inoremap <A-b> <C-o>b
inoremap <A-w> <C-o>w
```

### (Other uses of <kbd>Alt</kbd> in Insert mode)

It is worth mentioning that there may be better uses for the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key than replicating Normal mode behaviour: e.g. here are mappings for copying from an adjacent line the portion from the current column till the end of the line:

```
" Insert the rest of the line below the cursor.
" Mnemonic: Elevate characters from below line
inoremap <A-e> 
    \<Esc>
    \jl
        \y$
    \hk
        \p
        \a
" Insert the rest of the line above the cursor.
" Mnemonic: Y depicts a funnel, through which the above line's characters pour onto the current line.
inoremap <A-y> 
    \<Esc>
    \kl
        \y$
    \hj
        \p
        \a
```

(I used `\` [line continuation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#line-continuation) and indentation to increase clarity. The commands are interpreted as if written on a single line.)

### Built-in hotkeys for editing

```
CTRL-H   delete the character  in front of the cursor (same as <Backspace>)
CTRL-W   delete the word       in front of the cursor
CTRL-U   delete all characters in front of the cursor (influenced by the 'backspace' option)
```

<sub>(There are no notable built-in hotkeys for movement in Insert mode.)</sub>

Reference: [`:help insert-index`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/index.txt.html#insert-index)

---

## Command-line mode

This set of mappings makes the upper <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>hjkl</kbd> **movements** available in the Command-line:

```
" provide hjkl movements in Command-line mode via the <Alt> modifier key
cnoremap <A-h> <Left>
cnoremap <A-j> <Down>
cnoremap <A-k> <Up>
cnoremap <A-l> <Right>
```

Alternatively, these mappings add the movements **both to Insert mode and Command-line mode** in one go:

```
" provide hjkl movements in Insert mode and Command-line mode via the <Alt> modifier key
noremap! <A-h> <Left>
noremap! <A-j> <Down>
noremap! <A-k> <Up>
noremap! <A-l> <Right>
```

The mapping commands for **pulling Normal mode commands to Command-line mode** look a bit different from the Insert mode mapping commands (because Command-line mode lacks Insert mode's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>):

```
" Normal mode command(s) go… --v <-- here
cnoremap <expr> <A-h> &cedit. 'h' .'<C-c>'
cnoremap <expr> <A-j> &cedit. 'j' .'<C-c>'
cnoremap <expr> <A-k> &cedit. 'k' .'<C-c>'
cnoremap <expr> <A-l> &cedit. 'l' .'<C-c>'

cnoremap <expr> <A-b> &cedit. 'b' .'<C-c>'
cnoremap <expr> <A-w> &cedit. 'w' .'<C-c>'
```

### Built-in hotkeys for movement and editing

```
CTRL-B       cursor to beginning of command-line
CTRL-E       cursor to end       of command-line

CTRL-F       opens the command-line window (unless a different key is specified in 'cedit')

CTRL-H       delete the character  in front of the cursor (same as <Backspace>)
CTRL-W       delete the word       in front of the cursor
CTRL-U       delete all characters in front of the cursor

CTRL-P       recall previous command-line from history (that matches pattern in front of the cursor)
CTRL-N       recall next     command-line from history (that matches pattern in front of the cursor)
<Up>         recall previous command-line from history (that matches pattern in front of the cursor)
<Down>       recall next     command-line from history (that matches pattern in front of the cursor)
<S-Up>       recall previous command-line from history
<S-Down>     recall next     command-line from history
<PageUp>     recall previous command-line from history
<PageDown>   recall next     command-line from history

<S-Left>     cursor one word left
<C-Left>     cursor one word left
<S-Right>    cursor one word right
<C-Right>    cursor one word right

<LeftMouse>  cursor at mouse click
```

Reference: [`:help ex-edit-index`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/index.txt.html#ex-edit-index)

Comment: @YugalJindle: Thanks! :)  I have now added info on tweaking the Command-line mode.  (The approach is a bit different from Insert mode.)

Comment: Shift - left/right to move an entire word!! How did I not know that. Thank you.

Comment: actually in terminal mode alt automatically sends esc before your commands........

Answer (score 35):

*If you are a vim purist, skip reading this answer. OTOH, if you are new to vim and are looking for a few helpful tips you wont find in the many hundred of vim tutorials and blogs, read on... :-)*

## A few un-orthodox (vim) ways

It's 2014, and as someone who's recently gone back to `vim` I can offer a few, potentially contrarian, points of view and tips.

### Use shift+left or shift+right to traverse words

While repetition is a powerful concept in vim, I (personally) find it strange that using it either forces me to count (lines, characters, words, etc.) or make guesses. My brain usually works like "I want the cursor *there*" and not like "I want the cursor _5_words_to_the_left_". Quickly being able to move the cursor, and visually observe where the insertion point this way allows me to keep my mind on what I'm editing instead of having to count how many hops I need to make to get to where I need to edit.

### Turn on mouse mode, and use the mouse wheel and clicking

...to navigate large bodies of text.

Most (all) modern computers have a **touchpad** that is closely integrated with the keyboard (e.g. MacBooks). Industrial designers have spent many man years optimizing these designs so that the old problem of having to move the hand away from the keyboard is no longer a real issue. Okay, it is if you are used to a mouse and don't like to switch, but for anyone new to vim (like those that might find this post via a search), this should not be much of an issue.

### As a bonus, click + drag puts you in visual mode

With mouse enabled, clicking and dragging has the effect of switching to visual mode and marking a region for yanking.

### And use the scroll wheel

Using the mouse (wheel) to scroll around, and clicking to position the cursor (duh) just works. See http://usevim.com/2012/05/16/mouse/ for more on this.

### And so...

These are what I'd call more modern (using mouse, scroll wheel, etc.) ways of navigating in vim, equally effective depending on your preference of input.

HTH

Comment: @MilesRout yes, I had a disclaimer. But in all seriousness, I would think there is a good proportion of vim users who's brains work the same as mine. That is ... my brain usually works like "I want the cursor there" and not like "I want the cursor _5_words_to_the_left_". And the conventional way of vim doesn't work that well for those people. I love vim because a) it is available everywhere and b) has powerful features. I don't however feel the need to conform to all it's default mechanisms.

Comment: @MilesRout There is a lot of religion around this sort of thing in vim, so I won't debate with you on this. The repetition count method doesn't help me, and the accepted answer also calls it out as something heavily underused. I can only guess why that is the case. Using w, b etc. for navigating to nearby places are all great, but for going further, the mouse wheel works a lot better for me. Cheers.

Comment: +1. I don't understand it down vote. There is a disclaimer. Take it if you like it and skip it if you don't.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer

Comment: As someone who has recently moved to VIM, I find the premise of this answer to be absolutely spot-on.The ability to instantly tell the number of repetitions necessary to position the cursor in a given spot might or might not be something that comes with experience. Right now, much as @ShyamHabarakada, my brain just doesn't work like that. Regardless of how unorthodox this might be, I personally re-mapped fn+hjkl to the arrow keys for very small movements. For big movements, I usually approximate a number of repetitions and then fine-tune with those. For me, that's as quick as I can get.

Comment: -1 for the person answering the question thoroughly and accurately, because you think the original author is asking the wrong questions?

Comment: @MilesRout I think you are wrong for thinking there are "wrong things" when it comes to something as both trivial (in the big picture of life) and personal as an editor. Murder is wrong. Using vim in a way that works for you, and sharing it because it might also work for other just can't be called "wrong."

Comment: Hi @JohnP, the original question remains to as _While in Insert Mode in Vim, is there any way to traverse the text (like moving some characters forward and backward) other than using the arrow keys ?_ I still think this is a perfectly valid answer. And it's one of many different approaches (as I've already indicated). HTH

Answer (score 15):

Many people in the Vim community argue that you should not navigate in Insert mode, that it is not the Vim way. I think this is an incorrect sentiment learned when transitioning from standard editors to Vim.

Vim is most powerful when you use its tools to create atomic, repeatable actions or finds.

It is ok to navigate while in Insert mode if you are fixing a mistake you made *in the same Insert session.* You should not navigate outside of the range of text you modified.

If you make a mistake while entering text and escape out of Insert mode to fix it you will not be able to repeat the intended action, `.` will repeat the correction.

Vim does support many Insert mode navigation keys. Obviously there are the arrow keys, Home, and End, but there are also many other shortcuts. See `:h ins-special-keys`.

Answer (score 7):

To have a little better navigation in insert mode, why not map some keys?

```
imap <C-b> <Left>
imap <C-f> <Right>
imap <C-e> <End>
imap <C-a> <Home>
" <C-a> is used to repeat last entered text. Override it, if its not needed
```

If you can work around making the Meta key work in your terminal, you can mock emacs mode even better. The navigation in **normal-mode** is way better, but for shorter movements it helps to stay in insert mode.

For longer jumps, I prefer the following default translation:

```
<Meta-b>    maps to     <Esc><C-left>
```

This shifts to **normal-mode** and goes back a word

Comment: I'm a big modal editing supporter, but Emacs has these little movements down so much that going from Vim to Emacs (evil) made me come looking for navigational improvements while in evil-insert mode only to find hacks and emulation of other editors (including emacs!).

You are simply expected to switch modes, even when it's more (inconvenient) button presses to do so. Switching modes and typing zza is more presses than C-l.

Answer (score 4):

In GVim, you can use the mouse. But honestly, what's wrong with using the arrow keys? There's a reason why they are on a keyboard.

Comment: but that reason is not catered to vim users. One of the central strengths of vim is that you can do all kinds of things without time-costly taking your hands off the keyboard home row. In particular, the hjkl movements.

Comment: I agree with @ammoQ. Nothing wrong with using the arrow keys. If using arrow keys give you more productivity, go with it.

Comment: accolade: I use hjkl more often than the arrow keys when using vi, but switching between modes has become a subconscious action for me.

Answer (score 2):

I believe <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> (and <kbd>PageUp</kbd>/<kbd>PageDn</kbd>) also work normally while in insert mode, but aside from that, I don't believe there are any other standard keys defined for text traversal.

Comment: but possibly isn't there any way of traversing the text using only the letter keys ?

Comment: Certainly there is, if you don't want to be able to type certain letters... ;)

Comment: @hobbs How about ctrl+hjkl? That should make sense

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but vim don't work that way.

You should switch to "normal" mode, navigate and then go back to insert again.

Answer (score 1):

You can create mappings that work in insert mode. The way to do that is via inoremap. Note the 'i' at the beginning of the command (noremap is useful to avoid key map collisions). The corollary is 'n' for 'normal' mode. You can surmise what vim thinks is 'normal' ;)

HOWEVER, you really want to navigate around in text using 'normal' mode. Vim is super at this kind of thing and all that power is available from normal mode. Vim already provides easy ways to get from normal mode to insert mode (e.g., i, I, a, A, o, O). The trick is to make it easy to get into normal mode. The way to do that is to remap escape to a more convient key. But you need one that won't conflict with your regular typing. I use:

```
inoremap jj <Esc>
```

Since jj (that's 2 j's typed one after the other quickly) doesn't seem to appear in my vocabulary. Other's will remap to where it's comfortable.

The other essential change I make is to switch the CAPSLOCK and CONTROL keys on my keyboard (using the host computer's keyboard configuration) since I almost never use CAPSLOCK and it has that big, beautiful button right where I want it. (This is common for Emacs users. The downside is when you find yourself on an 'unfixed' keyboard! Aaarggh!)

Once you remap CAPSLOCK, you can comfortably use the following insert mode remappings:

Keeping in mind that some keys are already mapped in insert mode (backwards-kill-word is C-w (Control-w) by default, you might already have the bindings you want. That said, I prefer C-h so in my .vimrc I have:

```
inoremap <C-h> <C-w>
```

BUT, you probably want the same muscle memory spasm in normal mode, so I also map C-h as:

```
nnoremap <C-h> db
```

(d)elete (b)ackwards accomplishes the same thing with the same key chord. This kind of quick edit is one that I find useful in practice for typos. But stick to normal mode for moving around in text and anything more than killing the previous word. Once you get into the habit of changing modes (using a remap of course), it will be much more efficient than remapping insert mode.

Comment: nice remap for escape - I reckon it’ll work for just about anything except transliterated arabic!

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, there is a way.**  You can use `gj` and `gk` inside ***Insert Mode*** to move up (backwards) and down (forwards) within a single logical-line that wraps around numerous visual-lines.  That is handy if you have very long lines and/or a narrow width terminal and can be much faster than the arrow keys, or hitting `ESC` to use the other navigation shortcuts.  Also you can use CTRL-O to issue one normal-mode command.  Neither of these navigation movements will escape you out of insert mode.

It can be disruptive to productivity to hit *ESC* (which was besides home-row on terminal keyboards when Vi was invented). I work with text files that have extremely long logical-lines, whole paragraphs of sentences full of plain text. These two options are a real time saver for me.  It's still handy to escape out to *normal-mode* if I need to hunt for a particular word within the paragraph, but many times I just need to move a visual-line up or down, and then continue inserting.

I actually edit my *.vimrc* to map out my nearly useless *ALT* key, so my left hand presses ALT while my right uses the arrow keys. (and it does not escape out of insert-mode: notice the "i" at the end of each entry).

```
imap <A-UP> <ESC>gki
imap <A-DOWN> <ESC>gji
```

I also add lines to *.vimrc* so that my arrow keys work in *normal-mode* to traverse up and down within many *visual-lines* that are contained by one *logical-line*  (the code is identical to the above except you use *map* or *nmap* rather than *imap*)  And I use keyboard's other navigation keys with the ALT-KEY, all within insert-mode.

I add additional navigation lines for my ALT key, to use with my keyboards preassigned navigation keys, to navigate more quickly within insert-mode.  None of these will escape you out of insert-mode:

```
" <ALT> navigation within insert-mode 
imap <A-UP> <ESC>gki 
imap <A-DOWN> <ESC>gji
imap <A-LEFT> <ESC>bi
imap <A-RIGHT> <ESC>ea
imap <A-END> <ESC>A
imap <A-PageUp> <ESC>(i
imap <A-PageDown> <ESC>l)i
imap <A-Home> <Esc>I
" so that <ALT> behaves the same in normal mode
nmap <A-UP> gk
nmap <A-DOWN> gj
nmap <A-LEFT> b
nmap <A-RIGHT> le  
nmap <A-END> $
nmap <A-PageUp> (
nmap <A-PageDown> )
nmap <A-Home> ^
```

My "within" insert-mode navigation short cuts utilize the ALT key with PgUp, PgDn, Home & End keys too, to jump around far more quickly. I use alt-pgup and alt-pgdn presses to jump forward or backward by sentences.  And, I use alt-home and alt-end to jump to the beginning and end of my paragraph long logical lines. None of this escapes me out of insert mode.  (I figured that I might as well program all the preassigned navigation keys to work quickly within insert-mode, without leaving it).  And if I want to move one character at a time, I just let up on the ALT key while still using the arrow keys.

All of those are really simple modifications to the .vimrc.  You can get creative and do all sorts of things to improve navigation within *insert-mode*.  Otherwise, if you use the plain ole ARROW keys within insert-mode on long lines, then you need a cup of coffee in your left hand to sip while you hold the arrow keys down with the right. That takes forever!

By the way, the  key already works with all the other normal mode navigation commands, like h,j,k,l and w,W,b,B,e and search: /,% etc.  EXCEPT that it automatically escapes you out of insert mode without having to press the ESC key.  So using  with the normal-mode navigation characters will leave you stranded in normal-mode, until you take the effort to press i,I,a,A,o,O again, which I find easy to forget to do.

Since the keyboards preassigned navigation commands: arrows: UP, DOWN, RIGHT, LEFT and PGUP, PGDN, HOME, END don't do anything special with the  key, I found that I might as well map them out in .vimrc to help my navigation within insert-mode, while staying within insert-mode.   And, to reiterate, its helpful to me because I work with very long text documents that have paragraph long logical-lines that span across a lot of visual-lines, and the arrow keys and h,j,k,l don't acknowledge the visual-lines.  This fixes that particular problem, both within insert-mode and normal-mode.

*I give credit to my knowledge above, which I found in the book HACKING VIM 7.2 by Kim Schulz*

Answer (score 0):

You could use `imap` to map any key in insert mode to one of the cursor keys. Like so:

```
imap h <Left>
```

Now h works like in normal mode, moving the cursor. (Mapping h in this way is obviously a bad choice)

Having said that I do not think the standard way of moving around in text using VIM is "not productive". There are lots of very powerful ways of traversing the text in normal mode (like using w and b, or / and ?, or f and F, etc.)

Comment: I didn't say the the standard way of moving through text in vim is not productive; what i said was that it was a bit "annoying" having to go out of insert mode to go back a few characters and then having to back to insert again; but then again, maybe this is because I haven't got quite used to vim yet :)

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for. I use imap <C-h> <Left> (i know it deletes a char, but I have backspace), which is all I need, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For some frequently used movements and actions, I have defined the following mappings. This saves a keystroke compared to the CTRL+O combination and since I need them frequently, they pay off in the long 
run.

```
inoremap <A-$> <C-o>$
inoremap <A-^> <C-o>^
inoremap <A-h> <Left>
inoremap <A-l> <Right>
inoremap <A-O> <C-O>O
inoremap <A-o> <C-o>o
```