# Vim - VSCode How to add navigation in insert mode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vim

I am trying to learn to use Vim using VSCode. I have added the VSCode extension in order to use Vim. But the main problem I am facing is that I find it difficult to navigate while being in inserting mode.

I have found that a lot of people have fixed this by adding a remap of the 'ctrl-j', 'ctrl-h',.. keys in order to move the cursor in insert mode.

I cannot find a solution to get this working in VSCode. I know that there is an option to add remaps in the 'settings.json' file. Inside this file there is a variable called 'vim.normalModeKeyBindings'. But I cannot get these maps to work.

Comment: I'm sure you've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737163/traversing-text-in-insert-mode/16137350#16137350) post? The normal vim way isn't really to navigate while being in insert mode. I would argue if you let go of navigating in insert mode, you'll learn all the cool ways to navigate and manipulate text outside of insert mode. Won't leave this as an answer since it's just a suggestion, but thought I'd leave this as food for thought. Have fun learning vim :)

Comment: Although, now that I read into the answers more in depth, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15703188/13020139) could be a good answer. With `ctrl + o` you can then do a single normal mode motion while staying in insert mode. Requires no remapping and you get to do some navigation in insert mode!

Comment: 1. Learning $TOOL is better done by using $TOOL than by using $OTHER_TOOL. 2. In Vim, you don't navigate in insert mode. Whatever trick you find that lets you do this is going to prevent you from learning Vim properly and handicap you. 3. If somehow you don't want modes, then there is no point whatsoever learning Vim as it is its central concept and its core value proposal.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> click to "Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)"

Paste this code:

```
// vim
  {
    "key": "ctrl+l",
    "command": "cursorRight",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.mode === 'Insert'"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+h",
    "command": "cursorLeft",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.mode === 'Insert'"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+j",
    "command": "cursorDown",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.mode === 'Insert'"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+k",
    "command": "cursorUp",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.mode === 'Insert'"
  },
```